# Does ddply subset every variable in a data frame?

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to apply a function to multiple subsets of a data frame. Within that function I'd like to  subset again by month using the `cut()` function and apply another function using `daply()`. For some reason, in the data frame that is passed to the first function, even though `str()` reports the data frame as having a smaller number of observations than that original full data frame, the variable I am trying to subset by is the bigger.

Some code to help me explain:

This code calls reads data and then calls `ddply()` in line 10. Lets suppose data has 85110 observations here.

```
fracStatsByMonthHour <- function(file,interval){
    library(plyr)
    print("reading")
    data <- readData(file)
    print("finding highs")
    data$hifrac <- isHighFractal(data$high,interval)
    print("finding lows")
    data$lofrac <- isLowFractal(data$low,interval)
    print("calculating stats")
    result <- ddply(data,c("month","hour"),fracStats)
    print("converting to numeric")
    result[,c(-1,-2)] <- sapply(result[,c(-1,-2)],as.numeric)
    result
}
```

The next function, `fracStats()`, the `cut()` function fails because it says the length of `data$datetime` is 85110, but data has only 7172 observations (as it is split by month and hour by ddply in the function above)

```
fracStats <- function(data){

    data$month <- cut(data$datetime, breaks = "month")            
    ranges <- daply(data, "month" , fracRange)
    mean <- mean(ranges)
    median <- median(ranges)
    mode <- names(sort(-table(ranges)))[1]
    sd <- sd(ranges)
    quants <- quantile(ranges, seq(0,1,0.1), type = 1)
    res <- c(mean,median,mode,sd,quants)
    names(res) <- c("mean","median","mode","sd",names(quants))
    res
}
```

What is going on here? How come the date time column wasn't split like the rest of them?

This is `str(data)` from inside `fracStatsByMonthHour()` from an actual run of the code:

````
'data.frame':   85110 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ symbol  : Factor w/ 1 level "EURUSD": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ datetime: POSIXlt, format: "2001-01-02 23:01:00" "2001-01-03 00:00:00" "2001-01-03 01:00:00" "2001-01-03 02:00:00" ...
 $ open    : num  0.951 0.951 0.95 0.95 0.95 ...
 $ high    : num  0.951 0.951 0.951 0.951 0.951 ...
 $ low     : num  0.951 0.949 0.95 0.95 0.95 ...
 $ close   : num  0.951 0.95 0.951 0.95 0.95 ...
 $ volume  : int  176 232 224 240 212 228 232 236 240 240 ...
 $ hour    : Factor w/ 24 levels "00","01","02",..: 24 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ month   : Factor w/ 12 levels "01","02","03",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ year    : Factor w/ 14 levels "2001","2002",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ hifrac  : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ lofrac  : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...```
````

and from within `fracStats()`:

````
'data.frame':   7172 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ symbol  : Factor w/ 1 level "EURUSD": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ datetime: POSIXlt, format: "2001-01-02 23:01:00" "2001-01-03 00:00:00" "2001-01-03 01:00:00" "2001-01-03 02:00:00" ...
 $ open    : num  0.951 0.951 0.95 0.95 0.95 ...
 $ high    : num  0.951 0.951 0.951 0.951 0.951 ...
 $ low     : num  0.951 0.949 0.95 0.95 0.95 ...
 $ close   : num  0.951 0.95 0.951 0.95 0.95 ...
 $ volume  : int  176 232 224 240 212 228 232 236 240 240 ...
 $ hour    : Factor w/ 24 levels "00","01","02",..: 24 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ month   : Factor w/ 12 levels "01","02","03",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ year    : Factor w/ 14 levels "2001","2002",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ hifrac  : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ lofrac  : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 - attr(*, "vars")= chr "month"```
````

and finally `str(data$datetime)` from within `fracStats()`:

```
POSIXlt[1:85110], format: "2001-01-02 23:01:00" "2001-01-03 00:00:00" "2001-01-03 01:00:00" "2001-01-03 02:00:00" "2001-01-03 03:00:00" ...
```

Why is it `1:85110` instead of `1:7172`?

Comment: You'll need to provide a `dput` of the data that is required to run the code. The `str` output is nice to know but not reproducible. And make sure the desired output is clearly defined.